# parametric subdomains in url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have a pretty url

eg:www.mydomain.co.in to subdomain.mydomain.co.in which works perfectly fine..

The problem that I am facing is that with parameters....
I am getting `subdomain.mydomain.co.in/category?id=250`....This has to be changed to`subdomain.mydomain.co.in/category/250` using only .htaccess..

Yes there are many links which works for www.mydomain.co.in?id=250 to www.mydomain.co.in/250..

what change that has to be made so that I include subdomains also.The output should be like `subdomain.mydomain.co.in/category/250`

.htaccess file is shown below

```
 RewriteEngine On

 #subdomain and folders
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.mydomain.co.in [NC]

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.mydomain.co.in/$1 [R=301,L]

 #remove .php and ad slash
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://mydomain.co.in/subdomain/$1 [R=301,L]

 # Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://mydomain.co.in/subdomain/$1 [R=301,L]

 # Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
 RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 new rules for handling `category`. Try this code:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 #subdomain and folders
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.mydomain.co.in [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.mydomain.co.in/$1 [R=301,L]

 #remove .php and ad slash
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://mydomain.co.in/subdomain/$1 [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(category)\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(category)/([^/.]+)/?$ /$1?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

 # Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://mydomain.co.in/subdomain/$1 [R=301,L]

 # Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
 RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: That could be due to css/js not loading. Try  try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />` OR else use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: ,googled it,but did nt get the logic behind this..Can you plz explain the logic behind `category` part please?

Comment: Oh sure. First rule is 301 rule that externally redirects from `/category?id=250` to `/category/250` whereas next rules is for internal rewrite then silently rewrites `/category/250` to `/category?id=250` thus loading right content and showing pretty URL in browser.